# Cakephp URL Slugs Question

Tags: url, cakephp, slug

my urls are like

example.com/deals/by_city/glasgow

I have an action "by_city" in a cities_controller that needs to grab the "glasgow" part of url and do stuff how can i do this with cakephp? I only want to know how to grab this part of the url and store it in variable.

All help appreciated :)

Thanks
Dave

Cities Controller

```
function city_changer($CitySlug = null) {
        $active = $this->City->find('first', array('conditions' => array('City.slug' => $CitySlug)));
        $cities = $this->City->find('all', array('order' => array('City.name', 'City.name ASC')));

        $this->set(compact('active', 'cities'));
    }
```

City changer.ctp

```
<h2>Daily Deals from <?php echo $active['City']['name'];?></h2>
<form>
    <select name="file" size="1" onchange="loadPage(this.form.elements[0])" target="_parent._top" onmouseclick="this.focus()">

<?php foreach($cities as $city) {?>        
        <option value="/new_avc/deals/by_city/<?php echo $city['City']['slug'];?>"><?php echo $city['City']['name'];?></option>
<?php }?> 

    </select>
</form>
```

default.ctp

```
<div id="header_wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Amazing Voucher Codes</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="city_nav">
            <?php echo $this->requestAction('/cities/city_changer/'.$city['City']['slug'], array('return'));?>
        </div>
```

As there is no database linked to default.ctp having problem getting the slug to pass to the controller :)

Comment: Could you clarify the question: Do you have action `by_city` in controller `deals` and you want to know how that action can use the parameter? Or do you have that URL as a string and you need to extract the last part of it? Or something else?

Comment: The [`SluggableBehavior`](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/models/behaviors/sluggable.php) can help you with creating those URL parts. Just attach it to your model and add a `slug` field to your table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no custom router rules intervene, the third parameter in the URL (after controller/action) is the first parameter passed to the action.

```
class CitiesController extends AppController {
    function by_city( $cityName ) {
        // $cityName == 'glascow'
    }
}
```

Comment: the only problem is, the city changer is in the header which doesn't use a controller or db so cant pass the $cityname to controller :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying that the link is in the layout file? It doesn't make any difference after you've clicked the link.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that you use `$city['City']['slug']` in the layout so your `requestAction` doesn't work because that variable isn't always set. This has nothing to do with your original question. Please post another question with your actual problem.

Comment: My original question is how would i make this work, if that wont make it work then what could i do to make it work. if i remove that and just send request action to the city changer it still does not pick it up

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to add a `$cityname` parameter to the `by_city` method in the `deals` controller: this will automatically receive the city name (*glasgow* from the url above).

Comment: the only problem is, the city changer is in the header which doesn't use a controller or db :)

Comment: The header is a view like any other: it renders data set in the controller method. Add the city name variable to your view data in the controller and you should b fine. You are mixing up access to the URL segment with rendering control.

Comment: sorry not sure what u mean :)

Comment: Your questions was how do you extract `glasgow` from a url like this: `example.com/deals/by_city/glasgow`. You do that using a controller method parameter that receives the URL segment. If you need to access a variable in the header file then you should also set the `city` variable in your controller (which will make it available to the `default.ctp` file) but that has nothing to do with accessing the URL segment in the controller.

Comment: so would that be  making it available in the app controller? :S